# Building an RV cover and garage

Tags: building

I'm a mech engineer student so I’m not too familiar with wood sagging and weight.
My biggest concern would be on the 40ft sides with the weight of the trusses and the sheet metal (not shown). Basically I’m asking if it’s doable as is rather than putting 4 poles per side.

https://utrgv-my.sharepoint.com/:b:/g/personal/ruben_cardenas01_utrgv_edu/ETIwjsxmgBxItHzxsT8wmncBzfsKJ6WR4Dgjs626NzHosg?e=PTrptb

Comment: It may be better to post your PDF's pictures here using the "mountain" icon in the post editor, so the pictures don't disappear when the PDF is removed one day and render the question undecipherable.

Comment: Wood has defined engineering properties, though they are rather more variable than steel.

Comment: You should also think in terms of redundancy for that structure. Typically columns in a structure like that are hardened against car impact by extending the concrete well above grade. Otherwise a car impact would bring down the structure pretty easily. I wouldn't be surprised if a column every 6 ft or so was cost optimal, especially if 18 ft beams were used so continuity remains after a single column loss. With that redundancy against column loss you could maybe save some money by skipping the concrete detailing against impact.

Comment: Is this a homework question (since you say you're a mech eng student)?  I'm concerned that your roof trusses are too long for the needed strengths for supporting a roof, and not having any ridge truss is likely a non-starter for any building permit you might need to get.  It also depends on what sort of wood you're planning on specifying.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please step away from the Microsoft kool-aid. Post images directly here using SE's built in image hosting service. Don't make us go to your external site where this question becomes completely useless once you decide you're done with those drawings and delete them. This is, basically, a link-only question as there isn't enough info _here_ to answer it. As it stands, you question is "is it doable?" and the answer is _obviously_ yes, we just don't know what _your_ solution is and if it'll work.

Comment: When you graduate, you will be at a point where you will be a licensed mechanical engineer and your stamp will be a safety certification, am I correct?   So how would you feel if a **structural engineer** stepped in front of you and designed reactor cooling pumps, and it's a hatchet job because that guy is a structural engineer not a M.E.? *It's like that in reverse*.  Just one example, look at your center posts. Look at the top of them. What keeps them from spreading?  BTW [this just happened](https://youtu.be/ifQ4LO3d77Q)

Comment: @Harper - Reinstate Monica, snow loads based on a 50 year return interval, where the guy in that video sounds silly to me. Probably isn't the 1 year in 50. There's a load combination that weights snow by 1.6 so that the 50 year return interval snow load comes and goes without incident. 1 inch of rain, a massive, days-long rainfall, adds about 5psf if totally captured. Dense, wet snow reaches up to about 20% of the density of water, so an inch of snow maxes out at about 1psf. His "45psf" sounds totally wrong. I feel betrayed: I thought I was going to witness an avalanche. Very disappointing.

Comment: @popham *LOL betting against Blancolirio on the facts is a bad, bad plan*.  The guy is certainly the most reliable Youtuber I watch, and I watch Technology Connections, NPR and Perun. If Juan didn't win a Pulitzer for the Oroville series, it's only because they don't have a category for it. But for stuff getting kinetic, try this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T6GOz845zJQ

Answer (score 1):

You should look into pre-engineered metal buildings. Such a structure might be cheaper and easier.

Live load for a roof is 20 psf. If you live in an area with lots of snow, then that can easily contribute 30 psf. Dead load is probably below 10 psf. The weight of trusses and sheet metal, therefore, isn't all that interesting in comparison to the live loads or snow loads. That, and deflections are usually only checked under unfactored live load, where designers don't care so much about deflection under dead load.

The 40 ft spans aren't a big deal structurally, and getting material that long delivered also isn't that big of a deal. The question is whether the price goes up or down when you add an additional post.

Unless your truss supplier can also manufacture some truss girders for you, those 40 ft spans will probably force you to use LVLs for your girders (you could probably find 28 ft long dimensional lumber for your 80 ft / 3 spans). For LVLs, you get EIs and bending strengths from supplier technical pamphlets, not design codes, as LVL stengths and stiffnesses haven't yet been incorporated into a standard like the National Design Specification. For dimensional lumber (the 28 ft long 2X12s or whatever from the hardware store) there's a document called the National Design Specification Supplement where you can find modulus of elasticity values for lumber species and grade (for deflection calculations you'd use the E values, where the Emin values are for buckling calculations). 28 ft long LVLs would probably be cheaper than dimensional lumber anyway, so I wouldn't bother looking much at dimensional lumber.

Comment: LVLs aren't really cheap, but in comparison to 28' dimensional lumber they're probably a walk in the park!